# How to get particular column in Json output from database

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a program that can select particular data from the JSON output from the database. Here's my code. thank in advance.

I tried this method `$('#Fname').val(data["first_name"]);` but it doesn't fetch inside the text input. Thank you again.

```php
if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false ) {
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mias") or die("Connection error occured!");

    $input = $_POST['name'];
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_students_enrolled WHERE student_id = '$input' ");

    $data = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#search_text").on("change paste keyup", function() {

        var name = $('#search_text').val();

        if ($.trim(name) != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/fillinputs.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { name:name },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#Fname').val(data["first_name"]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ```data[0]['first_name']``` I also tried this code, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

So I started to explore and I found the answer to my own question.
Btw, Thank you so much for those who visit these questions.

BEFORE

```
                url: "php/fillinputs.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { name:name },
                success: function(data)
```

AFTER

```
            url: "php/fillinputs.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { name:name },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
```

I just add the `dataType: "json",` for the whole ajax method to get the value of the array data.